# Filter is causing everything to filter out even though condition is correct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope this will be easy for the reader. The where clause at the bottom causes nothing to show up on the result. When I comment it, I get all the values for what we need to test but we need to filter US, US, US.

Here is the following data or a subset.

| ACCT_DATE | ACCT_CD | STATUS | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-01 19:34:34.000 | A20 | ACCT | US | US | UK |
| 2021-11-01 19:34:57.000 | A20 | ACCT | US | US | US |
| 2021-11-01 19:34:57.000 | A20 | ACCT | US | US | US |
| 2021-11-01 19:34:34.000 | A20 | ACCT | US | US | UK |
| 2021-11-01 19:34:57.000 | A20 | ACCT | US | US | UK |
| 2021-11-01 19:34:57.000 | A20 | ACCT | US | US | US |

This is the filter that is not working:

```
(a.BRANCH_CD != 'US' and b.BRANCH_CD != 'US' and c.BRANCH_CD != 'US')
```

But you can see that the last record matches these conditions.

I can't put the entire query in this question as this is a proprietary system.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a series of table joins and a `GROUP BY`.

I believe maybe the group by is causing us the problem.

If someone can PM me, I could show you the code and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Axwick. If I understood you correctly and you need to filter out rows where A='US', B='US' and C='US', you would need to write `WHERE NOT(A='US' AND B='US' AND C='US')`. Equivalent would be `WHERE (A<>'US' OR B<>'US' OR C<>'US')`.

Comment: What you want is if one of the values is not 'US' - include the row?  You can try something like: NOT (a.BRANCH_CD = 'US' AND b.BRANCH_CD = 'US' AND c.BRANCH_CD = 'US').

Comment: The last record does ***NOT*** match the conditions! Those stipulate: neither the `A`, nor the `B`, nor the `C` can be `US`- which is **clearly** ***NOT*** the case for the last record...

Comment: @TT when I try that. I get nothing. For some reason it filters out the data that we do want included. I have  code that does what you say.

Comment: @marc_s I am not clear what you are saying. What would be filter then? I want the last record out and the rest in.

Comment: Then you have something else going on. Please provide a minimum data set (by way of a create table statement and data inserts) and a complete query that shows your problem. You can for instance provide a [DB<> Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) script and link to that in your question.

Comment: @Jeff' worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff helped on this and this worked as one would expect
NOT (a.BRANCH_CD = 'US' AND b.BRANCH_CD = 'US' AND c.BRANCH_CD = 'US').

Not sure why the inverse doesn't work. I think SQL Server is malfunctioning :)

Comment: Because `NOT (a.BRANCH_CD = 'US' AND b.BRANCH_CD = 'US' AND c.BRANCH_CD = 'US')` is not the inverse of `(a.BRANCH_CD != 'US' and b.BRANCH_CD != 'US' and c.BRANCH_CD != 'US')`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: This isn't a SQL Server problem. It is de Morgan's Theorem